# Timeout in function with ajax jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Good afternoon people !

I have the following code in jquery / ajax

```
$.ajax({
                url:'../pujar',
                 dataType:'json',
                type:'get',
                cache:true,
               });
```

This code works correctly when I send the php but now I don't know how to use the timeout with ajax.

In another code I use the following structure and I don't have any problem with code.

```
setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '../ajaxpujas',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'get',
        cache: true,
        success: json,
    });

    function json(data) {
        $("#tbodyid")
            .empty();
        $(data)
            .each(function(index, value) {
                var table = '<tr><td>' + value.users.name + '</td><td>' + value.id + '</td></tr>';
                $('#tbodyid')
                    .append(table);
            });
    }

}, 1000);
```

When I try to use this code , doesn't work correctly. I need to reload every second.

```
$.ajax({
            url:'../pujar',
             dataType:'json',
            type:'get',
            cache:true,
            timeout:1000,
           });
```

Comment: What exactly you want?

Comment: I need to reload this code every second to send the ajax petition.

Comment: So, You are having problem with last ajax `timeout:1000,`

Comment: exactly , what are the correct form with timeour or I should use setInterval function?

Comment: You state that you have code working that does exactly what you want. Why don't you use that code with your new ajax options then? "_In another code I use the following structure and I don't have any problem with code._"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

> Set a timeout (in milliseconds) for the request. This will override any global timeout set with $.ajaxSetup(). The timeout period starts at the point the $.ajax call is made; if several other requests are in progress and the browser has no connections available, it is possible for a request to time out before it can be sent. In jQuery 1.4.x and below, the XMLHttpRequest object will be in an invalid state if the request times out; accessing any object members may throw an exception. In Firefox 3.0+ only, script and JSONP requests cannot be cancelled by a timeout; the script will run even if it arrives after the timeout period.

`timeout` in `$.ajax()` sSet a timeout (in milliseconds) for the request to complete, if for any reason the request is not completed with in the time frame the request will abort

You have to use

```
setInterval(function() {      
    $.ajax({
        url: '../pujar',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'get',
        cache: true,
        success: function (data) {
        }
    });
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 2):

The "timeout" that you are using in the AJAX request is not the same as setTimeout in javascript. AJAX timeout actually specifies the time in which the request should get timed out.

As per jquery's documentation

> timeout
>   Type: Number
>   Set a timeout (in milliseconds) for the request. This will override any global timeout set with $.ajaxSetup(). The timeout period starts at the point the $.ajax call is made; if several other requests are in progress and the browser has no connections available, it is possible for a request to time out before it can be sent.

Hence you are actually setting a timeout for your request (i.e. if the source doesn't respond in 1000ms consider it to be a timeout failure). Thus you have to reload it every second.

What you are trying to do with the setInterval would work. Though I would recommend using setTimeout recursively instead of setInterval for better performance (and the intended effect I guess).